# BIOS Hard drive selection menu is not correct

Tags: hard-drive, bios

i have 2 hard drives. I have Windows 10 in one disk and Linux Mint another disk. Anyway, in my BIOS boot selection menu, there is ubuntu and debian options but ubuntu and debian isn't installed in my computer. How can i delete this options?

(I had installed ubuntu and debian a long time ago. When i choose them, it boots Windows 10.)

My motherboard: Gigabyte H61M-S2PV

[BIOS Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pREmZ.jpg)

Comment: Linux Mint is a derivative of Ubuntu, which in turn is a derivate of Debian. Maybe thats why they are showing ?

Comment: Okay, i get it what you said but i mean it is not related actually. I mean, i installed Linux Mint today but this menu looks like this for a long time. When I only have Windows 10 in one disk and another disk is free, this menu looked same again. After all, when i choose ubuntu and debian, it boots Windows 10.

Comment: I used EasyUEFI and removed the options. Thanks for help!